# Generate unit tests for my code by using IntelliTest

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellitest

I found that I can use **IntelliTest** to generate unit tests for my code. I am using **Visual Studio Enterprise 2019**, but I don't see this option when I right-click on a method.

[image: Visual Studio]

Should I download something?

Comment: Tagging this because I have the same issue, and I am running both an up to date version of 2019 Enterprise, and 2019 Enterprise Pre-release.

Answer (score 1):

TL&DR:  Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 also does NOT have this capability!

> IntelliTest is available in Enterprise edition only. It is supported
> for C# code that targets the .NET Framework. .NET Core and .NET
> Standard are not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to my answer on  [Visual Studio 2019 IntelliTest Compatibility With .NET Core, .NET Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845243/visual-studio-2019-intellitest-compatibility-with-net-core-net-standard) ? In a nutshell, if your app targets .NET Core there is a bug that needs to be upvoted in order to have this functionality fix.