# Visual Studio 2019 IntelliTest Compatibility With .NET Core, .NET Standard?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellitest

I'm evaluating Intellitest in the latest version of Visual Studio Enterprise. As far as I can tell from my own attempts and research on various sites, it appears like IntelliTest is only compatible with .NET Framework - not .NET Standard, nor .NET Core.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per today's version (16.4.4) this seems correct. There is an open issue at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/359250/add-intellitest-support-for-net-corestandard.html which will add/fix the Intellitest option for .NET core and .NET Standard. You can help by  upvoting that item in order to have it prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, they are not supported yet!

> Note
>
> IntelliTest is available in Enterprise edition only. It is supported for C# code that targets the .NET Framework. .NET Core and .NET Standard are not currently supported.

Source: [Overview of Microsoft IntelliTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/intellitest-manual/?view=vs-2022)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30471018)

Answer (score 0):

TL&DR: Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 still does NOT have support for Dotnet Core

> IntelliTest is available in Enterprise edition only. It is supported
> for C# code that targets the .NET Framework. .NET Core and .NET
> Standard are not currently supported.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/intellitest-manual/?view=vs-2022